# Is there a TypeScript compatible way to access associated entities with Sequelize?

Tags: typescript, model, associations, sequelize.js

I am developing a TypeScript application running Sequelize. This is a minimal example model:

```
import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize';

export interface MyAttribute {
    id: number,
    descr: string
}

export interface MyInstance extends Sequelize.Instance<MyAttribute>, MyAttribute { }

export interface MyModel extends Sequelize.Model<MyInstance, MyAttribute> { }

export default class MyManager {

    //[...]

    constructor() {

        this.model = this.sequelize.define<MyInstance, MyAttribute>("MyEntity", {
            id: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            },
            descr: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            }
        });
    }

    public initRelations() {
        this.model.belongsTo(OtherModel.model);
        this.model.sync({force:true});
    }
}
```

Now I want to access the associated entities of OtherModel through a MyInstance object. I tried *getOtherModels()* but this is not valid during TypeScript compilation. Is there any other means of accessing the associated entity and its properties that is possible in this TypeScript environment?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize will add the methods such as `getOtherModels` at runtime to the object,so you just have to tell Typescript that they will exist on `MyModel` instances at runtime so you can use them:

```
export interface MyInstance extends Sequelize.Instance<MyAttribute>, MyAttribute { 
    getOtherModels(): Promise<OtherModel[]>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I tried your approach and added "getMeals(): Promise<Meal[]>;" to my Instance interface while providing a "as: 'Meal'" attribute to the options object at the initialization of the association with belongsTo(). So this should definitely match in my opinion.
However I get no "getMeals()" method at runtime (observed using the VS code debugging console). Is there any trick left I need to do?